# Exclude a controller from before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I am using the `before_action` filter to call `authenticate` which is a method that will redirect users back to their home page if they aren't authorized to be on the page requested.

I would like to exclude a page from this step, just for testing purposes.

What I have seen so far is that I can use `except` to exclude certain controller actions from being subject to the `before_action` filter so like:

```
before_action :authenticate, except: :demo_login
```

I can also exclude more than one action at a time like this:

```
before_action :authenticate, except [:demo_login, :demo_show]
```

#### How can I exclude all actions in a specific controller?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `skip_before_action :authenticate` in the relevant controller.

The format of this method is the same as `before_action` so if you want to skip calling `:authenticate` for a specific controller action, use:

`skip_before_action :authenticate, only: [:show, :index]`

The `except:` keyword can also be used.

Comment: the before action may exist in an inherited controller. is there a way to exclude the controller not the action in the parent controller?

Comment: `except:` works well